# React Router v6 no JSX or Toolchain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use React without JSX (please no examples/suggestions regarding NPM toolchains or Babel). Could someone provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to facilitate learning the new v6 React Router?

Here's what I tried:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')).render(
  //React.createElement('p', null, 'A paragraph')
  React.createElement(ReactRouterDOM.Link, {to: 'somewhere'}, 'A link')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js"></script>
```

This gives me this error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useHref')
>     at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:416:16)
>     at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16315:20)
>     at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19236:22)
>     at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21646:18)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4151:16)
>     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4200:18)
>     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4264:33)
>     at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27461:9)
>     at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26570:14)
>     at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26476:7)
> ```

Comment: You are not rendering the `Link` component within a routing context, e.g. one of the RRD router components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const e = React.createElement;
const RouterProvider = ReactRouterDOM.RouterProvider;
const createBrowserRouter = ReactRouterDOM.createBrowserRouter;
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
    e(RouterProvider, {
        router: createBrowserRouter([
            { path: "/", element: [e("h1", null, "Home"), e(Link, { to: "/about" }, "About")] },
            { path: "/about", element: [e("h1", null, "About"), e(Link, { to: "/" }, "Home")] },
            { path: "/js", element: [e("h1", null, "/js route worked"), e(Link, { to: "/" }, "Home")] },
        ]),
    })
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@remix-run/router/dist/router.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/dist/umd/react-router.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js"></script>
```